# How do you make a fluid wrapping divider height?

Tags: css, html, height

my friend did this but he wont tell me how he did it, but

I want my wrapper divider to have a fluid height.

So it should have an exact margin from the top and from the bottom at 30px, and then the wrapper itself can expand related to the browser height, but it will always be a specific distance from the top and bottom of the browser.

And is it also possible to make a minimum height so it doesn't get squished too much, and becomes a scrollable page?

Comment: What is the URL of your friend's page? It would be very easy for us to tell you *exactly* how it's being done with a live example.

Comment: I saw something that seems like this, having to do with a footer div; not sure if this will help. Basically, as it was described to me, a negative margin or padding was used to place the div below the content area. I thought it was clever but I never actually looked into how this was pulled off.

Comment: the answer, obviously, is that you need better friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divider should have the following properties. This will give it a 30px top and bottom margin and it will adjust with your window height.

```
.divider{
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 bottom:30px;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/zkebs/

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to put some padding on `<body>` to simulate a margin on your `<div>` and then make your `<div>` 100% height:

```
<html>
    <body style="padding: 50px;">
        <div style="background: #eee; height: 100%;">
            Where is pancake house?
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Block elements are full width by default so you don't have to worry about that part.
The background color is just for illustrative purposes.

You can use `min-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;` if you want to limit the height and get a scrollbar when necessary.

Comment: height percentages don't work in css as far as I know... Only if you have a specific height measurement to inherit from.

Comment: @Ninjiangstar: Height percentages are with respect to the parent element, they work just fine.

Comment: the height percentage that I've tested only inherits from a parent element other than the <body> parent. and the parent has to have an exact height in order for the percentage to function

Comment: @Ninjiangstar: Um, the `<body>` does have a rather specific height. Your confusion is when the parent element has an auto height so you'd get a feedback loop between the parent and child heights.

Comment: nevermind... it's weird because the 100% doesn't work for one site but works by itself if directly copied from your code... it does not for my more complicated website

Comment: @Ninjiangstar: Well Hussein's is probably the most reliable, you'd probably want to add `left:30px` and `right:30px` to it to get a nice box though.