# Width of a divider 100% minus a few pixels

Tags: css, width

the image below will explain what I mean

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siXXr.png)

pretending that the red area is **not** a divider since I just want it to be empty with a fluid-like divider

```
position:absolute; left:0px; right:100px;
```

the above thing wont work because im trying to do this with a table inside a divider that is already using the position:absolute.... and it's actually for height but to make explaining simpler im just asking for the width

Comment: "it's actually for height but to make explaining simpler im just asking for the width".. that's funny, somehow :) anyway, it's not really a good idea as the browser has different behavhiours trying to fill width and height (e.g. horizontal centering vs  vertical centering)

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616231/how-do-you-make-a-fluid-wrapping-divider-height.

Comment: no that was the question to get the wrapper in place... this is the question to get a table in place inside the placed wrapper since the absolute positioning won't work for this situation

Answer (score 0):

Your specific question is rather confusing, but, no, CSS has no concept of math. You can't do 100% - 50px, for instance, even though that would be really handy.

However, you can give elements margins of specific measurements, and if you don't give the element a defined width, it is, by default, 'auto' so will take up the remaining space.

So the left DIV could be set with a 100px right-margin.

That would answer your question if it were about CSS and horizontal spacing of a fluid layout.

As for your vertical spacing issues and a table, that's really an entirely different thing, so would suggest you revise your question with the specific markup you are looking for help on.

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes across this... CSS3 can now do maths: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/CSS-layout-gets-smarter-with-calc

Comment: Excellent idea to add this comment, just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You could have a loot to less css framework (it deals with js)

you can use operators, check the Functions & Operations in [less official website](http://www.lesscss.org/#synopsis), very interesting, you can do things like:

```
@base-color: #000000;
    #footer { 
      color: @base-color + #003300;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: calc(100% -100px);` but it's not supported by all browsers unfortunately.